# Only opening a Window only when it already is not open in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a button in tkinter with its command being to create anew window. But I don't want it to create a new window every time I click the create a new window button. I want to tell the program to open the new window only if it is not already open. If somewhere in the background the window is already open and the user presses the create a new window button I want it to move that window on the first layer of the user's screen (bringing it upfront from all the other open windows).

Here is my code --

```
def main():
    main_bg = "Gray"
    main_fg = "White"
    
    import tkinter as tk

    employees = []
    

    window = tk.Tk()

    window.configure(bg=main_bg)
    window.title("Business app")
    window.geometry("1100x650")


    def open_new_window():
        random_window = tk.Toplevel(window)

        random_window.configure(bg=main_bg)
        random_window.geometry("600x600")

    random_button = tk.Button(window, text="Do Something", font="Times 32", bg=main_bg, fg=main_fg, command=open_new_window)
    random_button.pack()




    window.mainloop()






if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have searched websites like Geeksforgeeks and this website but I could not find the solution I was looking for. Please help.

NOTE -- PLEASE DO NOT CLOSE THIS QUESTION AND POINT ME TOWARDS ANOTHER FORUM BECAUSE I HAVE CHECKED OTHERS IN THIS WEBSITE AS I MENTIONED ABOVE

Answer (score 1):

Added `grab_set()` will prevent open new window again.

```
def open_new_window():
    random_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
     
    #random_window.configure(bg=main_bg)
    random_window.geometry("600x600")
    random_window.grab_set()
```

Result:

[image]

When you click `Do Something` will prevent open new window. Unless close the `topelevel` window and then open new window again

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer, your solution worked. However, I am noticing that I can not minimize the random_window (the window you open by clicking the button). This might be a problem by my part but I just wanted to make sure. If you face the same issue can you please help with that too?

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference to the widget, and then check the reference to see if it's set. If it is set, you can then call `winfo_exists` to check whether the reference points to an existing window.

```
random_window = None
...
def open_new_window():
    global random_window
    if random_window and random_window.winfo_exists():
        # the window exists, so do nothing
        return

    random_window = tk.Toplevel(window)

    random_window.configure(bg=main_bg)
    random_window.geometry("600x600")
```